# How to display fetched JSON data in sectioned table

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have J SON data which i want to display in Sections table i have 63 dates and inside each date there are multiple events. So how should i display

following is the link of data which i have parsed 
http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a table view showing all the dates. When the user presses on a date you show a new table view with that date's events.

This is probably the simplest way - you just need two UITableViewControllers and a UINavigationController; you can do all that in xibs.

There are other options; when the user presses on a date you could animate in a new view with the events for that date? or you could make a calendar UIView and display the events on that (like the calendar app in the iPhone).

Personally, I'd just go with the simplest solution to begin with :)

Answer (score 0):

there's an error on your page.

For JSON, I recommand you to put the response into a NSString, and finally in a NSDictionary. Then, There's a magic method: objectforkey:@"theKeyOfTheJSONSearched"

Comment: What error? It seems like valid JSON to me (checked by cutting and pasting the URL into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)